# Deserializing a Java Binary Tree from a String

Tags: java, serialization, tree, binary-tree

My question is a tiny bit different from the results I found, and I haven't used Java in quite a while (novice), so I need some clarification.

Basically, I'm pretty sure my implementation is mostly correct, I just wanted to give some back story to what I was doing.

So, my real problem is that I have serialized a binary tree to a string:

```
      1
   2     3
 4   5
```

as:

```
1 2 4 # # 5 # # 3 # #
```

where the # are just null nodes.

My problem comes when I'm trying to rebuild it from the string. I've been doing some digging for quite a few hours, but I think I'm overcomplicating it. I just need to know the simplest way to read the string as such (delimited by whitespace):

the first element is 1, so we will change that to an int and make a node with that as the element. The next is 2, so do the same, then 4. The next is a #, so we ignore that as there is no leaf, etc.

then, I need to send the remaining part of the string (minus what has already been read from the front) into a recursive call.

In summary, my question is basically "what's the easiest way to parse it as described, and send the remaining string into a recursive call?"

Answer (score 2):

Below is my code to serialize a binary and deserialize a binary tree.
We just dump the tree in preorder into a string.
Here, I used code from Rahul, but I modified it to be more concise.

```
public class DeSerializationBinaryTree {
    public static String serialize(Node root) {
        if (root == null)
            return "# ";
        else {
            return root.val + " " + serialize(root.left) + serialize(root.right);
        }
    }

    public static Node deserialize(String res) {
        String[] tokens = res.trim().split("\\s+");
        return deserialize(tokens);
    }

    static int index = 0;

    private static Node deserialize(String[] stringArray) {
        if (index >= stringArray.length)
            return null;
        if (stringArray[index].equals("#")) {
            index++;
            return null;
        }

        int value = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[index]);
        Node tree = new Node(value);
        index++;
        tree.left = deserialize(stringArray);
        tree.right = deserialize(stringArray);
        return tree;
    }

    private static void inorder(Node root) {
        if (root != null) {
            inorder(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.val);
            inorder(root.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = new Node(30);
        Node node1 = new Node(10);
        Node node2 = new Node(20);
        Node node3 = new Node(50);
        Node node4 = new Node(45);
        Node node5 = new Node(35);
        root.left = node1;
        root.right = node2;
        node1.left = node3;
        node2.left = node4;
        node2.right = node5;

        System.out.println(serialize(root));
        Node node = deserialize("30 10 50 # # # 20 45 # # 35 # # ");
        inorder(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use parentheses when serializing the tree to a string:

```
1(2(3 4) 5(6))
```

Describes the tree:

```
         1
       /   \
      /     \
     /       \
    2         5
   / \       / 
  /   \     /    
 3     4   6
```

There is some ambiguity when you have just one child because you can't tell whether the child is a left or a right child. In that case you can have an explicit "no child" character:

```
1(2(3 4) 5(# 6))     //6 is the right child
1(2(3 4) 5(6 #))     //6 is the left child
```

So when parsing it, whenever you encounter an opening parenthesis you're looking at the children of the current node. When you encounter a closing parenthesis you know you're done with the children of that node and so you can fall back to the previous level.

Comment: The existing syntax is unambiguous if you interpret it as the OP describes in his question.  It is basically a pre-order depth first traversal, outputting '#' each time a null is encountered.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, if you have a specified order of traversal then there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

use this java method..consider you have string array...

```
private static Tree<Integer> deserialize(Tree<Integer> tree,
        String[] stringArray) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(index>=stringArray.length)
        return null;
    if(stringArray[index].equals("#")){
        index++;
        return null;

    }
    int value=Integer.parseInt(stringArray[index]);
    tree=new Tree<Integer>(value);
    index++;
    tree.left=deserialize(tree.left, stringArray);
    tree.right=deserialize(tree.right, stringArray);
    return tree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to know the simplest way to read the string as such (delimited by whitespace)

Create a `Scanner` from the String, and use `hasInt()` / `nextInt()` and `next()`.  Something like this:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(inputString);
    s.setDelimiters("\\s+");
    ...

    if (s.hasInt()) {
        int = s.nextInt();
        // ... create a node and recurse twice to populate its children
    } else if (s.next().equals("#")) {
        // ... this is a null node
    } else {
        // ... syntax error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int index =0;  

/**
 * Saves this tree to a file.
 * @param filename the name of the file in which to save this tree; 
 *              if null, uses default file name
 * @return   <code>true</code> if successful save
 *          <code>false</code> otherwise
 * @throws IOException if unexpected IO error 
 */

public final boolean save(String filename) throws IOException{
    List<String> sbtList = new ArrayList<>();
    sbtList = preOrderSerialize(this, sbtList);
    for (String sbtList1 : sbtList) {
        System.out.println(sbtList1);
    }
    try{
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream (filename);
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        output.writeObject(sbtList);

    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Save not successful" + e);
        return false;
    }
    finally { 
        output.close(); 
    }
   return true;
}
/**
 * The pre-order traversal to serialize a binary tree
 * @param sbt
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private List<String> preOrderSerialize(StringBinaryTree sbt, List<String> myList){ 
    if (sbt == null){ 
        myList.add("# ");
    }           
    else{
        //sbt.add(this.value + "");
        myList.add(this.value + " ");
        preOrderSerialize(sbt.leftNode, myList);
        preOrderSerialize(sbt.rightNode, myList);
    }
   return myList;
}

/**
 * Restores this tree from a file. 
 * @param filename the name of the file from which to restore the tree;
 * if <code>null</code>, uses default file name.
 * @return <code>true</code> if successful restore
 *          <code>false</code> otherwise
 * @throws IOException if there is an IO issue
 */
public final boolean restore(String filename) throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream (filename);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream (file);
        input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
        try{
            List <String> restoreSBT = (List<String>)input.readObject();
            StringBinaryTree root = deSerialize (restoreSBT);
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.err.println("File Not Restored" + ex);
        return false;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("Cannot read file: Class Not Found"+ e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private StringBinaryTree deSerialize(List<String> restoreSBT ){
    if (index >= restoreSBT.size()){
        return null; 
    }
    if (restoreSBT.get(index).equals("#")){
        index ++;
        return null;
    }
    StringBinaryTree root = new StringBinaryTree (restoreSBT.get(index));
    index++;
    root.leftNode = deSerialize(restoreSBT);
    root.rightNode = deSerialize(restoreSBT);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent allowed on Stackoverflow